# Why imgradient invert vertical when computing the angle

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

why in the matlab function imgradient the angle computed as

```
 Gdir = atan2(-Gy,Gx)*180/pi; % Radians to degrees
```

and not

```
Gdir = atan2(Gy,Gx)*180/pi; % Radians to degrees
```

as I expected?

is it a mistake in matlab or something else?

Comment: not sure, but a typical coordinate system has its origin in the bottom left. A Matlab matrix has the origin in the top left. Inverting the y-coordinate may compensate for that. It's just a guess though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the previous comment is on the right track; image coordinate space has the y-axis with the [0,0] pixel being the top left corner, but the standard MATLAB trig functions expect a standard Cartesian coordinate system. Therefore MATLAB must be trying to automatically account for this by inverting the y-coordinate.